# When adding more text in the column (twitter bootstrap) alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating 4 rows by three column layout. I have created as it is how the tutorial was showing from bootstrap. Here my question was.  When I entered more letter in the first columns it was not the first row was not equally adjusting. and the output was the last column came down.  But if I have minimum characters in my first column then the output was correct.

Here I am not understanding why it was equally adjusting.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="firstdiv" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Checking whether height is longer and bigger than other column</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 2</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 3</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 5</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 6</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 7</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 8</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 9</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 10</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 11</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 12</p></div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="seconddiv" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 1</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 2</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 3</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 5</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 6</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 7</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 8</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 9</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 10</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 11</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 12</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know how to create fiddle for bootstrap.

My Output of the firstdiv should be look like second div.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/ - a jsfiddle like site for bootstrap :)

Comment: Can you put your code into Bootply for us to look at it?